# How can I setState with setInterval after received data from API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to create a count-down timer that can receive time from the backend for OTP form.

Let me explain the situation

1. User clicks the button and then send the request to the server
2. Received data from the server and store it into the redux store
3. use useEffect in function component to hooks when data in the redux store changed
4. set data from the redux store with useState
5. (I want to) call setInterval after setState

Here is my code

```js
const OTP = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const state = useSelector(state => state);

  const otpRef = state
    ? state.otp
      ? state.otp.refCode
      : undefined
    : undefined;

  const [otpDetails, setOtpDetails] = useState({
    remainingTime: 60,
    otpRef: undefined,
    otp: ''
  });

  // useEffect will trigger if `refCode` in redux store changed
  useEffect(() => {
    if (otpRef) {
      setOtpDetails({
        ...otpDetails,
        otpRef
      });
      
      // I want to trigger setInterval after setOtpDetails here
      // and count down time from 60 to 0
      // if count down time is 0, it can send request OTP again
      // it count down time is not 0, the button will be disable
    }
  }, [otpRef]);
  
  return (
    <div>
        <input onChange={(e) => setOtpDetails({...otpDetails, otp: e.target.value})}/>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(requestOTP())}>Request OTP</button>
        <span>Time remaining: {otpDetails.remainingTime}</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I create a simple component to show you all.
It can count time and stop when time is 0, BUT it will render many times. How can I fix it?

```js
function App() {
  const [store, setStore] = useState({ data: undefined });
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({
    id: 0,
    time: undefined,
  });

  useDidMountEffect(() => {
    setDetails({ ...details, time: store.data.time });
  }, [store.data]);

  useDidMountEffect(() => {
    function startCountdown(seconds) {
      let counter = seconds;

      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        counter--;

        if (counter < 0) {
          console.log("Ding!");
          return clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
          return setDetails({ ...details, time: details.time - 1 });
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
    startCountdown(details.time);
  }, [details.time]);

  const otpClick = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://mocki.io/v1/031caafe-f817-4b54-8614-4e56fc7f228c"
    );
    const respJson = await response.json();
    // setStore({ data: respJson });
    setStore({ data: { time: 3 } });
  };

  console.log(details);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <button onClick={() => otpClick()} disabled={details.time === 0}>
          Request OTP
        </button>
        <span>TIME : {details.time}</span>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to add `setInterval` in _another_ `useEffect` hook that depends on `otpDetails` state: `useEffect(() => { ... }, [otpDetails])`

Comment: I added the new useEffect like this `  useEffect(() => setInterval(() => setOtpDetails({ ...otpDetails, remainingTime: otpDetails.remainingTime - 1 }, 1000), [otpDetails]);
`
But It starts working immediately when refresh. (I prefer to start working when click the button)

Answer (score 0):

Using `setTimeout` instead

```js
...

  useDidMountEffect(() => {
    const token = setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);

    return function cleanUp() {
      clearTimeout(token);
    };
  }, [details.time]);

  function updateTime() {
    if (details.time > 0) {
      setDetails({ ...details, time: details.time - 1 });
    }
  }

...
```